# Possible to take content in email and added to a new record in Google Sheet?

Tags: email, google-sheets, attachment

I am trying to do the following.  Whenever someone fills up a form in WordPress (ninja form), it will send an email with all the content of the form.

Is it possible to pass the content through the email to add a new record in Google Sheet?

The reason I am doing this way is because I don't want to spend money to buy an add-on.

If not, what about pass the info via a CSV attachment file in the email?

Comment: I think it would be easier to use a [ninja form webhook](https://ninjaforms.com/extensions/webhooks/) and send the data directly to a [google script web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I used Zapier's parse email to pass the info to Google sheet.